# How to update App files (html) in IOS?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, html

My app is really simple. I have a few plists with file names of html files. When user selects a row, webview loads that html file with its content. Im curious how to approach app updates? For example: I have a new updated html file, with corrections, that I would like user to download by clicking a button in the app. I would like the old file(html) to be replaced by a new one. Is there a way to do this? Not really sure where to start, hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. Im assuming, there would be no way to update the plist, I would have to switch from plist to a database, but the question still remains, how do I get the app to download the new file and replace the old one?

Thank you

Just to elaborate a bit more.

I guess im trying to figure out the right way to do accomplish update within my app. My html files are within the app, im assuming i might have the app initally connect to the internet and download the latest content files(html,plists), place them into documents folder and then update my home screen plist file? Is this the correct train of thought?

I do not want the app to be internet only, need those html files to be available off line.

Comment: Just ship a new version of your app with the updated plist and HTML files?

Comment: where are the HTML files stored?  within the app itself (in which case @Devraj's comment is valid) or are they downloaded by the app and stored somewhere else (e.g. in the "Documents" directory), or are they hosted and viewed from a remote server? or?

Comment: If they are stored on a remote server, just update the files on the remote server.

Comment: I know i can release a new version of the app, but the approval process takes like 7 days. And i was hoping to avoid that if i have to correct a minor typo. On the other hand since im not really changing the program, it would be useful to just push all the new html files to the app and update plist refrences. It would be easy to host the files on the remote server and have the user access them, but the problem arises when the user does not have internet connection and the whole purpose of the app, it to have that data be available even if there is no internet connection.

Comment: HTML files are stored within the app, but now that i think about it, it would make sense to store them on the documents folder? just have the app connect to the internet to download latest content. Thanks for all the replies.

Comment: You could have default versions of the files in the app bundle, and then have the app check occasionally to see if there are newer versions on the server. If so, the app could download the new versions to the Documents directory. The app would then simply use the versions in the Documents directory if available, and otherwise fall back to using the default versions in the app bundle.

Answer (score 1):

As many suggested, i figured my plan would be to download the content from the web, save it in the library folder and then load the content from there. within the app i will have the update button that whenever user chooses will connect to the server and update the content. Found sample code at apple.com ( https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html )

Will tweak a bit and it should work fine, this also might help if trying to download multiple files. [Downloading multiple files in iphone app(Objective c)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016040/downloading-multiple-files-in-iphone-appobjective-c)

```
- (IBAction)down
{
    // Create the request.
    NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://abc.com/missing.html"]
                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                          timeoutInterval:60.0];
    // create the connection with the request
    // and start loading the data
    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    NSString *msg;
    if (theConnection) {
        // Create the NSMutableData to hold the received data.
        // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
        receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];



    } else {
        // Inform the user that the connection failed.


    }

}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    // This method is called when the server has determined that it
    // has enough information to create the NSURLResponse.

    // It can be called multiple times, for example in the case of a
    // redirect, so each time we reset the data.


    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
    [receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    // Append the new data to receivedData.
    //You can also use the connection:didReceiveData: method to provide an indication of the connection’s progress to the user.
    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.

    NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data %@",data,nil ];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"-download-" 
                                                    message:msg
                                                   delegate:nil 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
   //NSLog ([[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"The value: %d  object: %@\n", alphArray.count, [alphArray objectAtIndex:1.1],nil]);

    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"the data %@",string);

    NSString *libraryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [libraryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Missing.html"];

    NSLog(@"Full path: %@", filePath);

    //NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);


    //write data to files
    [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

    [receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
  didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // release the connection, and the data object
    [connection release];
    // receivedData is declared as a method instance elsewhere
    [receivedData release];

    // inform the user
    NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
          [error localizedDescription],
          [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // do something with the data
    // receivedData is declared as a method instance elsewhere
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[receivedData length]);

    // release the connection, and the data object
    [connection release];
    [receivedData release];
}

-(NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
                 willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse
{
    NSCachedURLResponse *newCachedResponse = cachedResponse;

    if ([[[[cachedResponse response] URL] scheme] isEqual:@"https"]) {
        newCachedResponse = nil;
    } else {
        NSDictionary *newUserInfo;
        newUserInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSDate date]
                                                  forKey:@"Cached Date"];
        newCachedResponse = [[[NSCachedURLResponse alloc]
                              initWithResponse:[cachedResponse response]
                              data:[cachedResponse data]
                              userInfo:newUserInfo
                              storagePolicy:[cachedResponse storagePolicy]]
                             autorelease];
         NSLog(@"Succeeded! Receive use:%@",newUserInfo);
    }
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %@ - use:%@",newCachedResponse);
    return newCachedResponse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store your HTML files on an external server.  And make changed to your app to load HTML files from your external sever instead from your app bundle.  So if you need to update the content of any HTML file, you can do it on your server.

Comment: It would be easy to host the files on the remote server and have the user access them, but the problem arises when the user does not have internet connection and the whole purpose of the app, it to have that data be available even if there is no internet connection.

Comment: Of course.  Your edited to the original question made it clearer and it seemed to be the right path.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the new html file name, you can directly write it to your plist file.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
    NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"settings.plist"];
NSMutableDictionary* newValueDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:docPath];
[newValueDict setObject:newHtmlPageValue forKey:@"myHtmlPage"];
[newValueDict writeToFile:docPath atomically:NO];
[newValueDict release];
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is exactly what you described.

My most common train is to check for the existence in documents, add them from the bundle if they are not there.

use them, and download new ones in the background. (if the internet is available).
replace the old ones with the new ones in the event a successful download happens.

And set a timeout of some type so you dont download a new one every second.

I like a day for my timeout.

and implement a way to check the version with the server. (MD5 Hash and filesize is a good not to mention small comparison)

Good luck

Comment: thanks, do you keep the files in the library or in the documents folder?

Comment: I put the files in a folder in the dictionary folder. just make sure that you have a way to expire those files and that you overwrite the old ones. If you just add new ones each time, then you will eventually fill up the device which is a bad practice.

Comment: yea i understand that, my plan is to overwrite the old files instantly in the library folder as the files are being downloaded

Comment: I recommend downloading them in one place. and then replacing them when they download successfully. Learn from my mistake. I have to rework my code because I did that. My project was images, but the outcome is the same. The download fails and overwrites the file and you are left with nothing.-