# Writing plist with Dictionary format

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, dictionary, plist

I am writing information to a plist file in the documents folder and I am around 90% of the way the way there (I think). I just need some help formatting the info I write correctly.

I need to write the data in this format:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
<dict>
    <key>Level</key>
    <string>0</string>
    <key>Top</key>
    <string>0</string>
    <key>Needed</key>
    <string>0</string>
    <key>Passed</key>
    <string>0</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>Level</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>Top</key>
    <string>5300</string>
    <key>Needed</key>
    <string>4000</string>
    <key>Passed</key>
    <string>Yes</string>
</dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

I am using this code to write to the file:

```
NSMutableDictionary *array = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]; 
[array setObject:field1.text forKey:@"Top"];
[array writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];
```

Which sets the key and puts in the value. But can someone help me to get it formatted correctly to look like the plist above.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an sample code:

```
  NSMutableArray *plistArray = [[ NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self dataFilePath]];
  NSLog(@"plistArray before additon: %@", plistArray);
  for (NSMutableDictionary *dict in plistArray)
  {
    //if you want to search for a record only otherwise remove the if statement
    if ([[dict objectForKey:@"Top"] isEqualToString:@"0"])  //this just an example, modify this per your needed
      [dict setObject:field1.text forKey:@"Top"];  //select which dictionary record to set the Top key
  }
  NSLog(@"plistArray after additon : %@", plistArray);
  [plistArray writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I'm still not getting anywhere :(

I read the file like this 
`[[array objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"Top"];`

i need to write back something similar so I can update the Key "Top" for different items in the dictionary. Something like:
`[[dict objectAtIndex:1]setObject:field1.text forkey:@"Top"];`
But that doesn't work.

Comment: It is not very clear on your terminology… This line:  [[array objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"Top"];  will extract for you the value corresponding to the key "Top" from the first record in the data that you have posted which is a string "0".  In you sample posted, you have two records.  Each record starts with a <dict> and ended with </dict>.

If you want to set field1.text to the key/value pair with key named "Top", there are two options:

Comment: (As stated in my answer as well) If you want to set the value for all occurrences of key "Top", do not use the if statement in my sample.  So, as in your posted data, the outcome would be changing '0" to field1.text and 5300 to field1.text ,etc.  But if you only need the change to apply for a particular record, then you need to use the if statement in my sample code to locate the right record so that you only change that particular record.

The easiest way to see how it works is by running my sample code against your posted data.

Comment: This might help:  The for loop in my sample code will step through each record (the dict variable in my sample code) in your posted data.

Answer (score 0):

If you right-click on the plist file, you should be able to open it in a text editor.  Can you copy-and-paste your format if you do that?  Or do you mean that you have too much data to write by hand and you're trying to write it by script?

Comment: Yes I can open it and edit it to set it up the way I want, thats not a problem, but when I write to the file I will only need to edit one dictionary item at a time.

    `<dict>
    <key>Level</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>Top</key>
    <string>5300</string>
    <key>Needed</key>
    <string>4000</string>
    <key>Passed</key>
    <string>Yes</string>
    </dict>`

So I need to set up something that says objectAtIndex:1 - forKey"whatever"

Comment: Here's an example I gave for how to update a plist file.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/11131175/792139

You will need some way to distinquish between different dict entries to use this.  Can you try tagging them somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is confused... you have a variable named `array`, but it is declared as a dictionary.  From your property list example, it looks like you want an array at the outer level, so your code should use `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: yeah sure thats just because I'm working off of other code. It doesn't matter what that is called, I don't know if it matters if its an array or a dictionary. I just need to be able to write to the file in the same format as I'm reading from it here skillsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSLog(@"dict count: %d", [skillsArray count]);
    
    topScore = [[skillsArray objectAtIndex:level]objectForKey:@"Top"];